# Controlling an automotive relay and a pulled up signal with one switch

Tags: mosfet, relay

I am trying to control an automotive relay and a pulled up signal.

When I press the push-button switch, I need to trigger the relay and ground the signal on a microcontroller pin.

When I simulate the circuit design, the voltage on node3 for triggering the relay is 9.949V. I need to get it to 12V. How can I do it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2xVoD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 12V coils are likely specified to work well at 10V too. What's the meaning of "5V pulled up signal to be grounded"?

Comment: there is a board with microcontroller and IO pin of it should '0' when the button is pressed.IO pin is pulled up with 5V and 1K resistor. We are trying to use second mosfet as momentary switch to make IO pin '0'.

Comment: What's the purpose of R3, is it some sort of heating element? It draws 1.44W.

Comment: Without it, M3 is always on saturation and led is always on. I got this schematic from one of my friend design and trying to implement. I can higher R3 as 100K to lower power.

Comment: Unless you have a specialized resistor, 100R means it will burn up...  Typical values for pull-downs are 4k7 or 10k.

Answer (score 1):

First, your *pulled up signal to be grounded* is never going to be grounded because you have an LED and resistor in the source circuit of M3, so there will be a voltage there that is \$V_{LED} + (I_{LED}\times 1k\Omega)\$

You might also move the relay to the drain side for low side switching. You should also have a spike diode across the relay coil.

As far as switching M3, if you want it's gate to go to +12V you could connect it to the switch through a resistor the same as you did M2.

Here's a general idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq4F7N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It would also be best to add a resistor to ground on the low side of the switch. This would guarantee the mosfets stay off when intended.

Comment: @Nedd Added one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A single DPDT relay should suffice.

[image]